# Angular $watch <button> value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two buttons, acting like radio group. Basically : if I click on a button, it is active and its value is watched by Angular $.watch().

I did it with real radio buttons :

HTML

```
<form id="switch-view">
                   <div class="radio-inline">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" ng-model="srcUrl" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="/me/has" checked="" >
                        Label 1
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-inline">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" ng-model="srcUrl" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="/me/wants">
                        Label 2
                      </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Angular :

```
$scope.$watch('srcUrl', function () {
    console.log($scope.srcUrl);
   $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url:  $scope.srcUrl,
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
   }).then(function(res){
        $scope.items = angular.fromJson(res.data)
            .sort($scope.SortByName)
            .map(function(e){
                e.image = $sce.trustAsHtml(e.image);
                return e;
            });
        $scope.newItems = $scope.items;
        if($scope.newItems.length === 0) {
            $scope.message = "";
        }
        //console.log($scope.items);
        $scope.checkPagination();
    });
});
```

The code above works as expected. Now I want this to work with the following HTML :

```
 <form id="switch-view">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary active" id="dash-btn-collection" ng-model="srcUrl" value="/me/has">Label 1</button>
                   <button class="btn btn-primary violet" id="dash-btn-wantlist" ng-model="srcUrl" value="/me/wants">Label 2</button>

                </form>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to have a behavior like the radios, maybe like this:

```
<form id="switch-view">
  <button class="btn btn-primary active" id="dash-btn-collection" ng-click="srcUrl = URL.HAS" ng-class="{'active': srcUrl == URL.HAS}">Label 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary violet" id="dash-btn-wantlist" ng-click="srcUrl = URL.WANTS" ng-class="{'active': srcUrl == URL.WANTS}">Label 2</button>    
</form>
```

The css-class "active" indicated the current active button there.

Maybe you want to remove the watcher and trigger the data loading with `ngClick`

Comment: I tried that before posting on SO, but it doesn't worked, I don't know why... Anyway, I also needed the ng-class stuff, so I choose your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the value may be sufficient:

```
<form id="switch-view">
    <button class="... active" id="dash-btn-collection" ng-click="srcUrl='/me/has' " >Label 1</button>
    <button class="... violet" id="dash-btn-wantlist" ng-click="srcUrl='/me/wants' " >Label 2</button>

 </form>
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on why this needs to be downvoted ?